# Adding an image to NSPersistentDocument

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have subclassed NSPersistentDocument class. I want to add an image to the document. I have an Image Well. How do I set it to a .jpg file?

Answer (score 0):

Load the JPEG file and set the resulting `NSImage` in a property of your document, using property syntax (`self.image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:…] autorelease]`). Meanwhile, in your nib, bind the image view's `value` binding to your document's `image` property.